# How to change display value for one to one field in django admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm looking to change the display value for a one to one field in the django admin dashboard. I want to prefix the user's name to the one to one field.

I'm able to successfully do it for a foreign key like this:

```
 def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'audio_module':
            return AudioModuleChoiceField(
                queryset=AudioModule.objects.filter(is_deleted=False).order_by('user__last_name')
            )
        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

However, I don't see any options in the docs to override a `formfield_for_onetoone`.

Currently, my form field looks like this:
[image]

`audio_module` has a FK to my user table. Like I said above, I'd like to prefix the user's name in front of the audio module in the dropdown so it'll be easier to identify audio modules for specific users.

i.e.
`John Doe - audio module 2`

How do I achieve this?

Comment: maybe overriding `formfield_for_choice_field` will do the trick? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_choice_field

Comment: hm doesnt seem to be doing the trick